# my binary to decimal converter in python , any suggestions?

Tags: python

I have just started coding and ı dont have any experiance this was my homework and i somehow managed to make it any suggestions ?

```
a = input("Please put in a binary number\n ")
b = len(a)+1
d=[]
for c in range(1,b):
    w = 2**(c-1) * int(a[-(c)])
    d.append(w)
e = sum(d)
print("Your decimal number is",e)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in answer:

```
a = int(input("Please put in a binary number\n "), 2) # where 2 is the base
print("Your decimal number is", int(a)) # base 10 is default
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use builtin features of the language. For example:

```
a = input('Please enter a binary number: ')
print(f'Your decimal number is {int(a, 2)}')
```

If you want to avoid the builtin facility then:

```
a = input('Please enter a binary number: ')
m = 1
r = 0
for d in a[::-1]:
    if d == '1':
        r += m
    m <<= 1
print(f'Your decimal number is {r}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try functions in python, such as `int()`

```
test = ['111011011111', '0b101']
for number in test:
    print(int(number, 2))
```

the result : 3807 and 5

> This function is extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built-in functionality for this:

```
a = input("Please put in a binary number\n ")
print(int(a, 2))
```

I believe you don't want to use this, so what you have to do is the following:

```
a = input("Please put in a binary number\n ")
d = []
# We iterate through the input in the reverse order
for index, bit in enumerate(a[::-1]):
    # We multiply each bit from the input with 2 to the power of the current index
    d.append((2 ** index) * int(bit))
# We sum the numbers
e = sum(d)
print("Your decimal number is", e)
```

Although this works, it can be optimized by using bit manipulations:

```
a = input('Please enter a binary number:\n ')
d = 0
for bit in a[::-1]:
    d = d << 1
    d += 1 if bit == '1' else 0
print(f'Your decimal number is {d}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comprehension and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
a = '1101001'  # a = 105
e = sum(int(b) << i for i, b in enumerate(a[::-1]))
print(e)

# Output
105
```

**Step by step**:

1. Reverse the string `a[::-1]`: `1101001` becomes `1001011`
2. Use enumerate on the reversed list:

```
>>> list(enumerate(a[::-1]))
[(0, '1'),  # (index, values)
 (1, '0'),
 (2, '0'),
 (3, '1'),
 (4, '0'),
 (5, '1'),
 (6, '1')]
```

3. Shift bits to the left:

```
>>> [int(b) << i for i, b in enumerate(a[::-1])]
[1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 32, 64]
```

4. Sum all elements of the list

```
>>> sum(int(b) << i for i, b in enumerate(a[::-1]))
105
```

Note: you can also replace `<< i` by `* 2**i`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of solving this problem:

1. Using the iterative method
2. Using in-built int() function

**ITERATIVE METHOD:**

```
binary = input("Enter binary number to convert it to decimal: ")

decimal, i = 0, 0, 0

while(binary != 0):
    remainder = binary % 10
    decimal += remainder * pow(2, i)
    binary = binary // 10
    i += 1

print("Decimal number: " + decimal)
```

**in-built int() METHOD**

```
binary = input("Enter binary number to convert it to decimal: ")

print(int(binary, 2))
```